# multi h CPM implementation

Tags: digital-communications, digital-filters

I have understood the math behind CPM. but recently I came across multi h CPM. I haven't found any good document to explain about multi h CPM. Can anybody explain the math behind it. and how it reduces bandwidth. or can point some good document to implement Tx and Rx.

Comment: Could you give us a link? Top of my head, I don't know what "multi h CPM" is, but chances are good it might be understandable if you pointed us in the right direction!

Comment: CPM stands for **Continuous Phase Modulation**, first officially published by T. Aulin and C.-E. Sunberg in 1981. Their paper can be found in IEEE Trans. Commun. COM-29, 1981.

Comment: Are you still working on Multi-h CPM signals lately? I've been working on them for a while. Maybe we can communicate together. The Multi-h CPM signal is a signal model based on the CPM signal whose modulation index h circulates between symbols. As for how to reduce the bandwidth, I am not clear, but the simulation is more narrow than a single exponential CPM bandwidth. Demodulation uses the method of maximum likelihood estimation combined with Viterbi decoding. I work on synchronization, and I've been having problems lately.